# Can approximation formula for period of larger angles in simple pendulum be used to calculate period of small angles?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, oscillators, approximations

Can approximation formula for period of larger angles in simple pendulum be used to calculate period of small angles?

Comment: Please identify what formula you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what formula you are using.

Usually the large-amplitude formula is given as a finite or infinite series expansion in powers of amplitude angle $\theta$. For example : $$\frac{T}{T_0}=1+\frac{1}{16}\theta^2+\frac{11}{3072}\theta^4+\frac{173}{737280}\theta^6+...$$ in which $T_0$ is the limiting small-angle period ($\theta \to 0$).

If you take an infinite number of terms this formula is exact (and therefore equally accurate) for all values of amplitude $\theta$. If you take a limited number of terms the accuracy increases as amplitude $\theta \to 0$. So such a series expansion formula will always be at least as accurate for smaller angles.

However, if the formula has been designed to maximize accuracy for a particular amplitude or a particular range of amplitudes, then its accuracy could be worse for all angles outside of this range, even small angles. For example the formula $$\frac{T}{T_0}\approx \frac{\ln (\cos \frac12 \theta)}{1-(\cos \frac 12 \theta)}$$ derived by [Lima & Arun](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0510206.pdf) is designed to be perfectly accurate at $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\frac12 \pi$. As you get further from both these values of $\theta$ the accuracy decreases. So the formula can be less accurate for a smaller amplitude.

Answer (score 0):

Large angle formula can be used for small angles if you assume the angle $\phi$ as sufficiently small. That means you can do a Taylor series expansion of the large angle formula only to linear orders in $\phi$, by neglecting quadratic and higher order terms.